# Jmeter JSON Extractor to get a token value inside a response

Tags: javascript, json, regex, jmeter

So Here is the response that I am getting, I am unable to extract "webToken", what should be JSON path expression... I have tried `$..webToken` and `$.webToken`.
I am trying to use this in JMeter so I can pass the value

```
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You response is not JSON so your expression will not work.

You can use this regexp:

> "webToken":"([^"]+?)"

Configuring [Regular_Expression_Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) this way.

[image]